# Dynamic Bootstrap website using Joomla's BackOffice

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, templates, joomla, module

I came here because I have a huge problem in my website, and I never worked before with some kind of platform like Joomla.
So in my work they asked me to do a website for their enterprise by using Joomla and Bootstrap, and use a template already made and change it a little bit to make it original.

Original template: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/

So that's what I did, I started working around CSS and PHP/Javascript files, and finished my template.
Now I want to implement this on Joomla, so they can access through BackOffice and change whatever they want, add/modify/remove news, etc.
But I don't know how to do it properly. I already saw a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O0XDelA2DE) where the guy created a XML File with all the folders, files and positions, but when I try to for example change the logo, it comes with a div and I can't take it off. Something like this:

**My template without Joomla modules, static website:**

http://s28.postimg.org/5oz476nwt/image.png
[image: My template without Joomla modules, static website]

**My template after modifying a logo through Joomla's BackOffice using Bootstrap Nav Module:**

http://s28.postimg.org/vl1osq07h/image.png
[image: My template after modifying]

**Here is a screenshot of what I did to change the logo on Joomla's Administrator interface**

http://s17.postimg.org/3ugt26evj/image.png
[image: what I did to change the logo]

---

And what would I have to do to keep for example that Menu style, and how would I add a news system dynamically on my website by using Joomla's BackOffice?

I am sorry if I am being in some way noobish, but I am not really familiarized with this kind of platforms and frameworks.

PS: Website is a One Page Template. / Can't post images/links because I don't have enough reputation.

Please I really need some help, I would be very grateful!

Take care,
Vítor Coelho

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start with: [Creating a basic Joomla! template](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template). This tutorial provide all the basic information you need to implement to your template in Joomla.

**The steps are:**

1. You have to create a **templateDetails.xml** file that you will define file structure and available module positions.
2. Rename your template page to **index.php** and add the appropriate code blocks to head section for css and js libraries.
3. Add the appropriate **Module Position** code to the places that you want to assign dynamic content (modules).

Once you finish you have to zip the files, install them under `Extensions -> Extension Manager` and enable it under `Extensions -> Template manager`.

Please note that you [don't have to implement bootstrap files](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks). You just have to add this code to the top of template file to load bootstrap libraries:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```

There are other options for [Jquery and Mootools libraries](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks) too.

Hope this helps

Comment: That template uses BootStrap 3.2 so the OP will need to implement it as Joomla's included version is only 2.1 era.

Comment: @cppl indeed, but it wasn't clarified in question details.